# How do I store steps of each actions on my application like on button click, list view cell click etc. of React JS components?

Tags: react-native

I want to store steps of each actions on my application like on button click, list view cell click etc. and also I don't want to include any code in existing React JS components. Suppose I have a component named Login and there I included a TouchableOpacity tag for button in render method of component lifecycle. Thus I don't want to include any code with TouchableOpacity and would be able to capture onPress of such TouchableOpacity.

For doing this, I think need to create a separate component which listen all events like onPress of TouchableOpacity but I unable to do this.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here listening to all events? Without changing the implementation of your buttons (and other things) the only thing I could think of is some sort of Higher Order Component that iterates over all the children and wire up a onPress event that also calls any onPress event listener attached. This is a very hack-y solution that I would recommend against.

Comment: Yes I want to listen all events that user action on. How can I create higher order component to achieve this?

Comment: You would first need to work out how to write a HOC (see: https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e#.iqqof9z2k) and then once you have one created you would then have to scale the children of each component that is wrapped in the HOC to inject a custom onPress handler that logs out the event. Out of interest: Why is creating your own touchableOpacity not a option? That would make this requirement much easier.